# Questions about short-circuit tasks using airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

As the title says, I'm trying to use a short circuit task in a dag, implementing the following logic：

```
task1 >> [task2.1, task2.2] >> [task3,task4] >> task5
```

Among them, task2.* is used as a short-circuit task，

1. Pass the result of task1 to task2.*, and judge whether to execute the tasks task3 and task4 of the next node,
2. When task2.1 returns true, then execute task3, otherwise, skip, similarly, the same is true for task2.2 and task4，
3. No matter whether task3 and task4 are executed, the execution of task5 only depends on a specific condition in the return value of task1, and it will be executed if it is met, but when task3 or task4 executed, task5 must be executed last.

**How to implement the above logic?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using pre_task5 to check condition for task5 execution.
At the same time, use `ignore_downstream_trigger_rules` and `trigger_rule` to determine the node trigger rules,
use `ShortCircuitOperator` or `@task.short_circuit` to create task nodes.

First, create task1 and return the conditions of each short-circuit task:

```py
@task(task_id="task1")
def parse_running_config(dag_run=None):
    dag_conf = dag_run.conf
    if not dag_conf:
        stamp = datetime.datetime.now().second
        short_circuit_config = {
            "condition_1": stamp % 2 == 0,
            "condition_2": stamp % 3 == 1,
            "condition_3": stamp % 5 == 0
        }
    else:
        short_circuit_config = dag_conf
    print(f"short_circuit_config: \n{json.dumps(short_circuit_config, indent=4)}")
    return short_circuit_config

start = parse_running_config()
```

Then create a short-circuit task:

```py
task2_1 = ShortCircuitOperator(
    task_id='task2_1',
    python_callable=lambda res: res['condition_1'],
    op_args=(start, ),
    ignore_downstream_trigger_rules=False
)

# ...

pre_task5 = ShortCircuitOperator(
    task_id='pre_task5',
    python_callable=lambda res: res['condition_3'],
    op_args=(start, ),
    trigger_rule=TriggerRule.NONE_FAILED,
    ignore_downstream_trigger_rules=False
)
```

Finally arrange dependencies:

```py
chain(start, [task2_1, task2_2], [task3, task4], pre_task5, task5)
```

[dag graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPwre.png)

**Is there any better way to do it?**

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, try using the `ignore_downstream_trigger_rules=False` in `ShortCircuitOperator` and `trigger_rule='all_done'` for task5.

```py
task2_1 = ShortCircuitOperator(task_id='task2_1',
                               python_callable=check2_1,
                               ignore_downstream_trigger_rules=False)

task5 = PythonOperator(task_id='task5',
                       python_callable=last_task,
                       trigger_rule='all_done')
```

For dependencies,

```py
task1 >> [task2_1, task2_2]
task2_1 >> task3
task2_2 >> task4
[task3, task4] >> task5
```

[image]

If task5 does not have a logic to execute depends on task1, you can add another `ShortCircuitOperator` before task5 and move `trigger_rule='all_done'` to the task.

Comment: TIA, task5 may not be executed, it is controlled by a certain condition in the return value of task1. BTW, the return value of task1 may be:

```code
{
    "task2_1_condition": true,
    "task2_2_condition": false,
    "task5_condition": true
}
```

Trigger execution conditions for task3, task4, task5.

Comment: the last comment is what I tried to mean for it to add another `ShortCircuitOperator`.  Alternatively, you can have 1 single `BranchPythonOperator` after `task1` to handle the condition.  However, your solution seems cleaner when it gets more conditions.